# Small DSL for SQLite's where clause

Tags: kotlin, sqlite, dsl

I've got an application with a filter that offers the user over 30 different search cirteria that I need to translate into an SQLite query. A small DSL should simplify creating more efficient `where` clauses without the need of using dozens of parameters or hardcoding everyting in the SQL itself.

### Example

I would use the DLS like this where I setup all the criteria. In the actual application there will be of course some `if`s here and there for unsued filters etc.

```
fun foo() {
    val where = where {
        and {
            "foo" isEqual 1
            or {
                "bar" isEqual 2
                "baz" isEqual 3
            }
            and(not = true) {
                "bar" isBetween 1..3
                "baz" startsWith "b"
            }
            "baz" isIn listOf(1, 2, 3).asSequence()
            "bax" isIn listOf("a", "B", "c").asSequence()
        }
    }
    val w = where.toString()
}
```

### Implementation

The implementation consists of the main class `Operator` rendering all the expressions and joining them with `and`s and `or`s into a `string`. It also provides the basic operator as `infix`.

```
class Operator(private val operator: String?, private val not: Boolean, parent: Operator? = null) {

    private val conditions = mutableListOf<Any>()

    init {
        parent?.conditions?.add(this)
    }

    infix fun String.isEqual(value: Any?) {
        conditions += IsEqual(this, value)
    }

    infix fun String.isNotEqual(value: Any?) {
        conditions += IsNotEqual(this, value)
    }

    infix fun <T> String.isLessThan(value: T) where T : Comparable<T> {
        conditions += Compare(this, value, "<")
    }

    infix fun <T> String.isGreaterThan(value: T) where T : Comparable<T> {
        conditions += Compare(this, value, ">")
    }

    infix fun <T> String.isLessThanOrEqual(value: T) where T : Comparable<T> {
        conditions += Compare(this, value, "<=")
    }

    infix fun <T> String.isGreaterThanOrEqual(value: T) where T : Comparable<T> {
        conditions += Compare(this, value, ">=")
    }

    infix fun <T> String.isBetween(value: ClosedRange<T>) where T : Comparable<T> {
        conditions += IsBetween(this, value)
    }

    infix fun String.startsWith(value: String) {
        conditions += IsLike(this, "$value%")
    }

    infix fun String.contains(value: String) {
        conditions += IsLike(this, "%$value%")
    }

    infix fun String.endsWith(value: String) {
        conditions += IsLike(this, "%$value")
    }

    infix fun <T: Any> String.isIn(values: Sequence<T>) {
        conditions += IsIn(this, values)
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        // no need for parentheses in single expressions
        val prefix = if (conditions.size > 1) "(" else ""
        val suffix = if (conditions.size > 1) ")" else ""
        return (if (not) "not " else "") + conditions.joinToString(" $operator ", prefix, suffix)
    }
}
```

A couple of other classes render such operators as `=`, `between` or `like`. I used SQL vocabulary at the beginning but it didn't work with `in`, so I changed it to `isX`.

```
class IsEqual(private val column: String, private val value: Any?) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return when (value) {
            null -> "$column is null"
            is String -> "$column = '$value' collate nocase"
            else -> "$column = $value"
        }
    }
}

class IsNotEqual(private val column: String, private val value: Any?) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return when (value) {
            null -> "$column is not null"
            is String -> "$column <> '$value' collate nocase"
            else -> "$column <> $value"
        }
    }
}

class Compare<T>(private val column: String, private val value: T, private val operator: String) where T : Comparable<T> {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$column $operator $value"
    }
}

class IsBetween<T>(private val column: String, private val value: ClosedRange<T>) where T : Comparable<T> {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$column between ${value.start} and ${value.endInclusive}"
    }
}

class IsLike(private val column: String, private val value: String) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$column like '$value' collate nocase"
    }
}

class IsIn<T : Any>(private val column: String, private val values: Sequence<T>) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$column in " + values.joinToString(prefix = "(", separator = ", ", postfix = ")") {
            if (it is String) "'$it'" else "$it"
        }
    }
}
```

The last part are the `where` function opening the scope and two logical operators. Here I don't like the duplication of the `and` operator, but I don't know how to refactor it differently.

```
fun where(condition: Operator.() -> Unit): Operator {
    return Operator("and", false).apply(condition)
}

fun Operator.and(not: Boolean = false, condition: Operator.() -> Unit) {
    Operator("and", not, this).apply(condition)
}

fun Operator.or(not: Boolean = false, condition: Operator.() -> Unit) {
    Operator("or", not, this).apply(condition)
}
```

---

One of my goals was to avoid any class inheritance, so please keep this in mind when reviewing. Otherwise, what would you improve?

Comment: You have `private val operator` as `String?` but everything I see seems to have a value. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Marvin the `operator` as `String` is the `and` or `or`. `value` is the right-hand-side of the `infix` operator like in `a isEqual b` where `b` is the `value`.

Comment: So the `operator` is never `null`? Why define it as nullable `String?` then?

Comment: @Marvin oh, didn't see that! Now that I see it, it's pretty sutpid though ;-] An enum would make even more sense... what was I thinking?